# How to add Active states and icons in wordpress wp_nav_menu()

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

```
function main_nav() { 
    wp_nav_menu( 
        array( 
            'menu' => 'main_nav', 
            'theme_location' => 'main_nav', 
            'container_class' => 'menu clearfix', 
            'link_before'     => '<span>',
            'link_after'      => '</span>',
            'fallback_cb' => 'bones_main_nav_fallback' 
        )
    );
}
```

I'm trying to use link_before and link_after to append a span tag to the wp_nav_menu so so that I may add an icon to each navigation.

**Example:**

```
<li><span><img src="home.gif" /></span><a href="home.php"> Home</a></li>
```

I am super super new to php and wordpress.  Any ideas on how to tackle this?

Secondary question,  Adding a css-class to the "current active state" anchor? Just for styling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you will need to change this code... but here is example. You can see the [Reference to wp_nav_menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) and add holder pattern... and later just change it by your local replaments settings (see array before replacements)

```
function main_nav() { 
    $menu = wp_nav_menu( 
        array( 
            'menu' => 'main_nav', 
            'theme_location' => 'main_nav', 
            'container_class' => 'menu clearfix', 
            'link_before'     => '<span></span>',
            'echo'            => $false,
            'fallback_cb' => 'bones_main_nav_fallback' 
        )
    );

    $patterns = array(
        '<span></span><a href="home.php"',
    );
    $replacements = array(  
        '<span><img src="home.gif" /></span><a href="home"'
    );

    echo str_repalce($patterns, $replacements, $menu); 

}
```

and btw, list items contain number of *current* classes so you able to use tham to track current item of your menu too.