# Set active state on navigation dynamically

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I seem to run into this problem frequently and can never find a solution. I have a Wordpress site with a top navigation. Since this is in my header.php, and used on all pages, I cannot hardcode my active menu state for each page.

How can I dynamically set the activate state to work for each page?

Here is my current nav code:

```
<nav id="main-menu" class="padbot">
<ul id="ce">
    <li class="cemenu"><a href="<?php echo $base_url;?>/about">About</a></li>
    <li class="cemenu"><a href="<?php echo $base_url;?>/consulting">Consulting</a></li>
    <li class="cemenu"><a href="<?php echo $base_url;?>/intelligence">Intelligence</a></li>
    <li class="cemenu"><a href="<?php echo $base_url;?>/academy">Academy</a></li>        
    <li class="cemenu"><a href="<?php echo $base_url;?>/blog">Blog</a></li>
    <li class="cemenu"><a href="<?php echo $base_url;?>/contact">Contact</a></li>
 </ul>
```

I've already setup a CSS class called "active" that has my active state properties. Ideally, what I'm looking for is when your on the "About" page (or any of the other pages), the class I created for the active state will be appended to the current li classes's.

Example:

```
<li class="cemenu active"><a href="<?php echo $base_url;?>/about">About</a></li>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the awesome question! #DIY all da way!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you could try something along the lines of

```
<li class="cemenu<?php echo ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == '/about' ? ' active' : '');?>"><a href="<?php echo $base_url;?>/about">About</a></li>
```

Comment: Hey Pete, this is almost working. For some reason, your: <?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?> is returning /index.php rather then /about

Comment: ah are you using url rewriting?

Comment: Hmm, in Wordpress I changed my permalinks to Post name

Comment: This is the URL in the address bar: /ibis/website/about/ but it's returning as: /ibis/website/index.php for all pages.

Comment: try $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] or do a print_r($_SERVER) to see which variable matches best - it's been a while since I did php!

Answer (score 5):

You can do this way:

This will add the `active` class to the `<a>` which contains the `page` from the url.

```
$(function(){
   var url = window.location.href;
   var page = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
   $('.cemenu a[href*="'+page+'"]').addClass('active');
});
```

and if you want to add class to its parent li the replace the last line to this and css class should be like this:

```
.active a{
      css 
      properties 
      for active li's a
}

 // using closest
$('.cemenu a[href*="'+page+'"]').closest('li').addClass('active');
```

or

```
// using parent
$('.cemenu a[href*="'+page+'"]').parent('li').addClass('active');
```

[**just tryout the fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Y8Mfw/)

Comment: Oh great, Glad to see that you got the solution for your issue. Thanks for the consideration.

Answer (score 1):

First, there is a css pseudo class prepared for styling 'active' links :

```
a:active {css}
```

For your situation, you would have to add this class to your styling :

```
.active a, a:active {css}
```

But your needs seems more on the PHP side than the CSS, perhaps someone else will help you with that part. There would be a javascript solution with jQuery, finding the actual location then inject a css selector to the proper element.

Check [this article](http://www.vanseodesign.com/wordpress/hightlight-current-page-wordpress/) and [this other one](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/navigation-active-state-problem) about wordpress. It will help you.

Stack Overflow references :

- [How do I target each menu different items on active state in Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6529155/how-do-i-target-each-menu-different-items-on-active-state-in-wordpress)
- [How to add Active states and icons in wordpress wp_nav_menu()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9858243/how-to-add-active-states-and-icons-in-wordpress-wp-nav-menu)
- [Loosing Nav Active State in Wordpress Dynamic Menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11942798/loosing-nav-active-state-in-wordpress-dynamic-menu)
- [google search](https://www.google.ca/search?num=100&hl=fr&newwindow=1&q=wordpress%20active%20state%20navigation%20site:stackoverflow.com&oq=wordpress%20active%20state%20navigation%20site:stackoverflow.com&gs_l=serp.3...320081.325972.0.326119.23.23.0.0.0.0.138.1639.22j1.23.0...0.0...1c.1.4.serp.2uc03Bkjn9E)

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

```
<?php $pages = array('about' => 'About Us', 'blog' => 'blog') ?>

<ul>
<?php foreach($pages as $url => $page): ?>
    <?php $isActive = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] == $url ?>
    <li<?php echo $isActive ? ' class="active"' : '' ?>>
        <a href="<?php echo $base_url . "/{$url}" ?>"><?php echo $page ?></a>
    </li>
<?php endforeach ?>
</ul>
```

It may be worth looking into using wordpres functions such as get_page_link which would be nicer than using the Server super global as that's not nice. This would also fail if you have wordpress in a folder and not the document root, it's just a simple example to get you started :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this

```
<li class="<?php 
                if($this_page=='Home'){
                     echo 'active';
                }
          ?>">
      Home
 </li>
<li class="<?php 
                if($this_page=='Contact'){
                     echo 'active';
                }
          ?>">
      Contact
 </li>
```

And then in your home page

```
$this_page='Home';
```

And in your contact page

```
$this_page='Contact';
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use preg_replace() to add `class="active"` like this:

```
ob_start();
echo '<ul>
  <li><a href="page1.php">Page 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="page2.php">Page 2</a></li>
  </ul>';
$output = ob_get_clean();
$pattern = '~<li><a href="'.$url.'">~';
$replacement = '<li class="active"><a href="'.$url.'">';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $output);
```