# Add a class to an ID in CSS

Tags: html, css

**Solution:** Followed solution provided by accepted answer.
Excerpt of my code provided below as a clearer solution.

```
<?php
$active_home = "active";
include('header.php');
?>


<div id="content">
    <title>Welcome to the home page.</title>
    <p>index</p>

</div>
```

The $active_home must come before the include in order to affect the header file.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="MainStyle.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>

    </head>

    <div class="topnav" id="mytopnav">
        <a href="/Index.php" id="homenav" class="<?php echo $active_home; ?>">Home</a>
    </div>
</html>
```

---

Currently I have a main CSS sheet, which specifies all the styles of my navigation bar.
I want to provide an indication as to what page the user is on, and [the tutorial I followed](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav.asp) makes use of a ".active" class which changes the background and text colour.
The trouble is that their method has the active page specified on the navbar. This doesn't work, as what the navbar considers to be the active page never changes.

What I am attempting to do, is add a small style sheet at the start of each page which sets the current page on the nav bar to active.
I can do this very easily if I use something like

```
<style>
#homenav{
    background-color: #4CAF50;
}
</style>
```

To each page, in the above example the home page.
However, this means that if I want to update the style for the active page, I need to change each page individually.

What I'd rather do is something like

```
<style>
#homenav{
    (add the .active class)
}
</style>
```

Which makes life easier, however at the moment I am having issues referencing.
**Is it possible in CSS to add a class to a particular ID? Failing that, is there a way to declare a variable in the main css that can be referred to in other style sheets?**

Main CSS:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
}

#body{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px; 
    font-family: Calibri;
}

.topnav {
    background-color: #333;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.topnav a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
}

 /*Change the color of links on hover */
.topnav a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
}

/* Add a color to the active/current link */
.topnav a.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: Are you talking about combining `#homenav` and `.active` into a single selector like `#homenav.active { // home nav id and active class }`?

Comment: Are all your pages dynamic or limited to the number of pages? The solution I want to propose may vary depending on that.

Comment: @MichaelCoker I would like to apply the properties of the .active class to the homenav element.

Comment: @MohammedAkhtarZuberi Dynamic, this is done with php hence why I have the issue at hand. Instead of having navbars for each page, I just have the one which I would like to alter slightly for each page by referring to the bar elements, if possible.

Comment: Got it. Wait for my answer now!

Comment: Then combine them via `#homenav, .active { // styles that apply to both }`

Comment: @MichaelCoker I'm not sure that's what I want, as the active is only meant to be for the page the user is currently on. What you seem to be suggesting unless I'm mistaken, is to apply the active style to homenav, but that'd only really be accurate if the user is on the home page.

Comment: Oh I see. You want to have `.active` in your global CSS, but on the "home" page, you want `#homenav` to have the class `.active` in the HTML so that the `.active` classes are applied to it?

Comment: @MichaelCoker Yes, there is one global nav bar, and the goal would be to have the style on each page apply the .active to the relevant tab.

Comment: You should dynamically add the `.active` class to the appropriate element in your HTML then. here's a way to do it in php and javascript. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15005731/set-active-state-on-navigation-dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current case scenario, you have dynamic pages where you want to highlight the menu in navbar related to the active page. It can be simply achieved using the below logic.

**In case you have fixed number of dynamic pages**
Let's take an example that you have the below navigation bar (menu) items.

1. Home
2. About
3. Services
4. Contact

In every page, you have dynamic content. What you require will be accomplished with PHP and NOT by HTML/CSS.

Have your Navigation Bar file as a separate file. Name it as you want. For example, `nav-items.php` and include in your PHP pages.

Now in `nav-items.php` apply the below logic:

```
<li id="home" class="<?php echo $active_home; ?>">Home</li>
<li id="about" class="<?php echo $active_about; ?>">About</li>
<li id="services" class="<?php echo $active_services; ?>">Services</li>
<li id="contact" class="<?php echo $active_contact; ?>">Contact</li>
```

In case you have dynamic pages in terms of count as well and you are not sure about the pages names, use the below code instead.

```
<?php
    $dynamic_page_name = "Page Name" //This is can be fetched from database
?>

<li id="<?php echo $dynamic_page_name; ?>" class="<?php echo ${"active_" . $dynamic_page_name}; ?>"><?php echo $dynamic_page_name; ?></li> //Since it is an example of dynamic page names, so I am only giving one List Item example.
```

Now in every PHP page, add the below code.

For example, About will have the below code:

```
<?php
    $active_about = "active";
?>
```

In case you have dynamic pages in terms of count as well and you are not sure about the pages names, use the below code instead.

```
<?php
    $dynamic_page_name = "Page Name" //This is can be fetched from database

    ${"active_" . $dynamic_page_name} = "active";
?>
```

This will add `active` class to each page with their specific PHP variables defined for this purpose only. So once the `nav-items.php` will be loaded in each page, only the relevant page will have `active` class added to it.